# PHP Session is not set using php & EXTJS

Tags: php, session, extjs

When I call a php file using Ajax, I do this :

```
function logIntoApp(){
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url:'php/login.php',
        params:{
                action:'login',
                email:Ext.getCmp('userLogin').getValue(),
                motDePasse:Ext.getCmp('passwordLogin').getValue()
        },
        method:'GET',
        success:function(result, request){
            //Ext.MessageBox.alert('Success', );
            if(result.responseText == 'admin'){
                //Ext.MessageBox.alert('Alert', result.responseText);
                window.location.replace("administration.php");
            }
            else if(result.responseText == 'pro'){
                //Ext.MessageBox.alert('Alert', result.responseText);
                window.location.replace("proAdministration.php");
            }
            else{
                Ext.MessageBox.alert('Alert', result.responseText);//'Email ou mot de passe incorrect!');
            }
        },
        failure:function(result, request){
            Ext.MessageBox.alert('Failed', 'Erreur de chargement de données');
        }
    });
}
```

in my php file, I set a $_SESSION to use it in my administration.php

```
if($role=='Administrateur'){
                    $_SESSION['role']='admin';
                    $_SESSION['email']=$email;
                    $message = 'admin';
                }
```

And in my administration.php, I have this :

```
<?php
session_start();
echo "alert(''". $_SESSION['role'] . ")";
    if($_SESSION['role']=='admin'){
        //echo "alert('pro')";
    }
    else{
        //echo "alert('admin')";
        header("Location:index.php");
    }
?>
```

And in my index.php I have this :

```
<?php

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['role']='visiteur';
    $_SESSION['email']='no';


?>
```

the problem is that I'm never redirected to administration.php, I think because the $_SESSION['role'] is never set as 'admin'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used UTF-8, the problem is that it send a BOM character befor the flow, so it considers that session_start() isn't the first thing sent.
I can use UTF-8 (without BOM).
Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm no ExtJS expert, but judging by the logic, your `result.responseText` is always equal to `alert('something')`, and never something simple as `admin` or `pro`, so it gets to the last `else` statement. Maybe you should fix the output sent by PHP, skip the `alert()`

Comment: I'm always using the content of result.responseText and always getting what I sent from the php, the problem is that the $_SESSION['role'] is not set in the php file

Comment: Did you do a var_dump($_SESSION) after session_start() and see the output?

Comment: I want to know something before, should I do session_start(); in all my files ???

Comment: I tried the var_dump($_SESSION) and it's not containing admin, it contains what it was set in the index.php

Comment: where do you set it to 'admin'? In what file? When do you call it? And to answer - you need session_start when you're using sessions. If it's a request to a file that's sending a bitstream of an image, and there is no need for sessions, don't start it.

Comment: I'm sending an authentification request using ajax to a php file, so, if the person is an admin, I set up the $_SESSION['role']='admin'; without doing the session_start(); because when I write session_start(); I have this message
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /homez.380/webadmin/www/wa/php/login.php:1) in /homez.380/webadmin/www/wa/php/login.php on line 2

Answer (score -1):

You should try session_start immediately after php  tag no spaces in between session start and php tag

Comment: how will no spaces help? You can start the session whenever you like, just make sure it's before using the $_SESSION superglobal, and yes, before sending any output.

Comment: That's irrelevant. You can have as many spaces/line breaks/tabs as you want between <?php and session_start();. Only thing that matters is that nothing is printed _before_ the php tag.